# Проблема завершения загрузки HTML-страницы при вызове Ajax-запроса с использованием XMLHttpRequest-объекта

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

**Код на чистом JS**.
Для запроса данных с сервера вызывается AJAX-функция с использованием `XMLHttpRequest`-объекта, запрос нормально завершается со статусом `200 (ОК)`, и все данные отлично переданы, обработаны и представлены в HTML-странице.

```
    Request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ...  

    // конфигурирация запроса
    r_method = "POST"
    Request.open(r_method, "/url/", true);  

    // Проверяем, если требуется сделать POST-запрос
    if (r_method.toLowerCase() == "post") {
        // Если это POST-запрос устанавливаем заголовки:
        Request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"); 

        // Посылаем запрос
        Request.send(JSON.stringify({'data': data}));
    }
    ... 

    if (Request.readyState == 4) {
        // Передаем управление обработчику пользователя
        console.log("Статус запроса: " + Request.status + ", текст статуса:" + Request.statusText); // 200, ОК
        r_handler(Request); 
    }
```

Обработчик `r_handler(Request)` извлекает из запроса данные, и далее сам `XMLHttpRequest`-объект не используется:

```
    r_handler(Request) {
        serv_response = eval('('+ Request.responseText +')');
        ...
        // Request.abort(); // результат не меняется - признака конца загрузки HTML-страницы нет
    }
```

Однако на этой же странице другой JS скрипт завязан на конструкции `"window.onload"` и всегда находится в ожидании конца загрузки страницы.

```
console.log("Скрипт работает");
window.onload = function () {
            console.log("Страница загружена");
}
```

Было однозначно установлено, что проблема именно в том, что HTML-страница ожидает конца загрузки, т.к. без конструкции `window.onload` всё отлично работает.
Пробовалось закрыть соединение после получения данных с помощью метода `.abort()`, но ничего не поменялось.

> *Без использования скрипта с XMLHttpRequest-объектом признак завершения загрузки на странице корректно срабатывает!*

**Что это за ситуация, и как всё-таки нормально достигнуть признака конца загрузки HTML-страницы в данном случае?**

Comment: Какой смысл вызывать `abort()` на объект запроса, который уже успешно завершился?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Где-то в другом месте (но *после* Вашего `window.onload = ...`) есть другой код, который делает то же самое (`window.onload = ...`) и затирает Ваш `window.onload` обработчик. Поэтому надо использовать

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  console.log("Страница загружена");
});
```

Comment: Да в искомом ajax-скрипте есть обработка события "DOMContentLoaded". Может ли  быть в этом дело? Корректно ли будет использовать предложенный Вами вариант в обоих скриптах?

Comment: @JBlack Не знаю. Вы слишком многого не договариваете.

Comment: Конструкция window.addEventListener("load", function(){...}) даёт требуемый результат - HTML-страница коррекно отрабатывает по признаку конца загрузки. При этом во втором скрипте использовалось событие "DOMContentLoaded" в контексте той же команды  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){...}). Благодарю за предложенное решение!